# Wordpress Multisite Rewrite Rules

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am running Wordpress 3.1 with multisite enabled. I have multiple websites all sharing the same .htaccess file in the web root directory. I am using RewriteCond to target specific websites and apply RewriteRules to each site. Unfortunately it is not working as expected. Here is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Blog1 Rewrite Rules which should only apply to blog1.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog1\.mydomain\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^fileabc\.jpg$ http://blog1.mydomain.com/files/2011/05/fileabc.jpg [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^filexyz\.pdf$ http://blog1.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/blog1Theme/Files/filexyz.pdf [R=301,NC,L]

# Blog2 Rewrite Riles which should only apply to blog2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^Blog2\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://Blog2.com/index.php [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page\.html$ http://Blog2.com/page/ [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I use RewriteCond to target a specific site (blog1.mydomain.com or blog2.com) and they have specific RewriteRules for each.

However, The ReWriteRules are being applied to both websites (blog1.mydomain.com and blog2.com).

For example:

Accessing blog1.mydomain.com/fileabc.jpg should redirect to http://blog1.mydomain.com/files/2011/05/fileabc.jpg

However, accessing Blog2.com/fileabc.jpg also redirects to http://blog1.mydomain.com/files/2011/05/fileabc.jpg

So the RewriteRules are being applied to both (all) site, not just the ones specified by the RewriteCond.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apache page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> The order of rules in the ruleset is
>   important because the rewrite engine
>   processes them in a particular (not
>   always obvious) order, as follows: The
>   rewrite engine loops through the
>   rulesets (each ruleset being made up
>   of RewriteRule directives, with or
>   without RewriteConds), rule by rule.
>   When a particular rule is matched,
>   mod_rewrite also checks the
>   corresponding conditions (RewriteCond
>   directives). For historical reasons
>   the conditions are given first, making
>   the control flow a little bit
>   long-winded.
>
> first the URL is matched against the
>   Pattern of a rule. If it does not
>   match, mod_rewrite immediately stops
>   processing that rule, and goes on to
>   the next rule. If the Pattern matches,
>   mod_rewrite checks for rule
>   conditions. If none are present, the
>   URL will be replaced with a new
>   string, constructed from the
>   Substitution string, and mod_rewrite
>   goes on to the next rule.

Now your rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog1\.mydomain\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^fileabc\.jpg$ http://blog1.mydomain.com/files/2011/05/fileabc.jpg [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^filexyz\.pdf$ http://blog1.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/blog1Theme/Files/filexyz.pdf [R=301,NC,L]
```

RewriteCond is valid only for first rewriteRule immediately following it , not for all rules  below it.So second rewriteRule will match any domain.

Comment: "RewriteCond is valid only for first rewriteRule immediately following it , not for all rules below it.So second rewriteRule will match any domain."

Very interesting. Thanks for the information and Apache link. So is there a way to make a RewriteCond apply to more then one RewriteRule? Or, is the correct way to repeat the RewriteCond:

    RewriteCond
    RewriteRule
    RewriteCond
    RewriteCond
    RewriteRule
    RewriteCond
    RewriteRule

Comment: technically its not possible but there are work arounds http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/1854.htm        , and feel free to upvote if you like the answer :)

Comment: "RewriteCond is valid only for first rewriteRule immediately following it , not for all rules below it." -- thanks, I received information that suggested otherwise. Thanks for this correction.